# Проблема с кодом для отправки сообщений по почте

Tags: c#, winforms

При вводе в textBox1 неправильную почту от программы 0 реакции, а когда ввожу правильную, то вылезают сообщения о неправильности почты + письмо отправлено. Где в коде ошибка?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = textBox1.Text;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("E:\\Login and Password.txt"))
        {
            string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (contents.Contains(text))
            {
                using (StreamReader kod = new StreamReader("E:\\Login and Password.txt"))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = kod.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        if (line.Contains($"{text}"))
                        {


                            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("sheldon71.golovin@rambler.ru", "OOO Golovini");
                            MailAddress toAdress = new MailAddress(text);
                            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAdress);
                            message.Body = ($"Пароль и логин: {contents}");
                            message.Subject = ("Восстановление");
                            message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.rambler.ru";
                            smtpClient.Port = 2525;
                            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                            smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, "SteamGuardsheldon75csgo");

                            smtpClient.Send(message);
                            {
                                if ((textBox1.Text.Contains("@")))

                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Сообщение отправлено!", "Почта", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                                }

                                      else

                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Не верно введена почта или неправилный формат почты. Пример: rambler@rambler.ru ", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                }
                                    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: А что в файле `Login and Password.txt`? Какая структура данных? Зачем вы его дважды открываете? Каша какая-то. Объясните, что вы хотите с даннми из файла сделать? Что вообще этот код должен сделать? Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: судя по коду, вообще без разницы, что у вас в textBox1, код и так и так отправит письмо.

Comment: @tym32167 не совсем так `if (contents.Contains(text))`, но то что в этом коде не легко разобраться - факт :)

Comment: в Login and Password пароль и зарегистрированная почта